# Why clang can not find Selected GCC installation?

Tags: gcc, clang, yum, mips64

My work environment as follow:

OS:  NeoKylin4

gcc: 4.4.7

Arch: Mips64el

I had used the yum to install the clang-v3.4.2,but when I used clang to compiler a c program,it showed me an error that **"/usr/bin/ld: crtbegin.o: No such file: No such file or directory"**.

I run the command "clang -v",and the output as follow:

```
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
Target: mips64el-neokylin-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Selected GCC installation:
```

As it haved shown above,clang can not find the Selected GCC installation.Now how can I  add the gcc installation path to clang so that the clang can work?